# Sequence of operations with RxJava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I want to do a sequence of operations. The next one can only execute if the previous was successful. To improve my understanding I decided to try to implement it with RxJava.

The operations, in order:

1. login
2. store the login result
3. use the login result to retrieve user info
4. store user info

For this I use the following:

```java
public interface LoginRepository {

    Single<LoginResponseEntity> login(@NonNull final Credentials credentials);

    Completable storeLoginResult(@NonNull final LoginResponseEntity loginEntity);
}
```

and

```java
public interface UserSettingsRepository {

    Single<UserInfoEntity> retrieveUserInfo(@NonNull final String email, final String accessToken);

    Completable storeUserInfo(@NonNull final UserInfoEntity userInfoEntity);
}
```

and the Login usecase:

```java
public Completable execute(@NonNull final Credentials credentials) {
    return loginRepository.login(credentials)
            .flatMap(loginEntity -> loginRepository.storeLoginResult(loginEntity)
                    .andThen(userSettingsRepository.retrieveUserInfo(credentials.getEmail(),
                            loginEntity.getAccessToken()))
            ).flatMapCompletable(userSettingsRepository::storeUserInfo)
            .andThen(saveIsAlreadyLogged.execute());
}
```

So to test this, I have created unit tests (in Kotlin). All pass, except these two:

```
@Test
fun `when storing login result failed, don't retrieve user info`() {
    val exception = Exception()
    whenever(loginRepository.login(any())).thenReturn(Single.just(loginResponseEntity()))
    whenever(loginRepository.storeLoginResult(any())).thenReturn(Completable.error(exception))
    whenever(saveIsAlreadyLogged.execute()).thenReturn(Completable.complete())

    val test = login.execute(credentials()).test()

    verify(userSettingsRepository, never()).retrieveUserInfo(anyString(), anyString())
}
```

error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked: 
userSettingsRepository.retrieveUserInfo(
    <any string>,
    <any string>
);
```

and

```
@Test
fun `when storing login result failed, login should error`() {
    val exception = Exception()
    whenever(loginRepository.login(any())).thenReturn(Single.just(loginResponseEntity()))
    whenever(loginRepository.storeLoginResult(any())).thenReturn(Completable.error(exception))
    whenever(saveIsAlreadyLogged.execute()).thenReturn(Completable.complete())

    val test = login.execute(credentials()).test()

    test.assertError(exception)
}
```

error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Error not present (latch = 0, values = 0, errors = 1, completions = 0)
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
And do you have tips on how to improve my code? Please give a clear explanation as I'm still learning.

Comment: You always execute the `userSettingsRepository.retrieveUserInfo` method even though the returned Single is not subscribed to due to the error. There could be a different error in `test` which should get printed along with that `AssertionError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case, the problem is in:

```
.andThen(
    userSettingsRepository.retrieveUserInfo(
        credentials.getEmail(),
        loginEntity.getAccessToken()
    )
)
```

Note that the call to `retrieveUserInfo` is done regardless of whatever happens to what you have before it. In other words: this is executed while your stream is being setup, and not when it's being run. You probably want to use [`Observable.defer`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html) to inside the `then` to match your expectations.

For the second problem, you can see that there IS an error happening:

`java.lang.AssertionError: Error not present (latch = 0, values = 0, errors = 1, completions = 0)`

`errors = 1` is indicating that, and you'll need to look at the full message to see what the error is (as @akarnokd pointed out)